# KineticJS - draggable shape with connections

Tags: javascript, canvas, draggable, kineticjs

I'm pretty new to KineticJS and have a problem with a draggable shape (circle) and a line, which connects this shape with another.
I'm not able to redraw the lines after moving the draggable shape. Maybe one of you can give me a hint.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kinetic.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        background: #EFEFEF;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    #canvas {
        display: block;
        background: white;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        margin: 50px auto;
        width: 700px;
        height: 500px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>


<h1>kinetic.js test</h1>

<div id="canvas"></div>

<script defer="defer">

    /**
     * get circle center coordinates
     *
     * @desc    gets coordinates of circle center
     * @param   shapeId     -   id of circle
     * @returns {object}    -   object with x and y coordinates
     */
    function getCircleCenterCoordinates(shapeId) {

        var shape = getShapeById(shapeId);

        if(typeof shape == 'object') {

            return {x: shape.shape.attrs.x, y: shape.shape.attrs.y}

        }

    }


    /**
     * get shape by id
     *
     * @desc    searches for given shape id and returns the matching
     * @param   shapeId     -   id of the circle
     * @returns {*}
     */
    function getShapeById(shapeId) {

        var result = jQuery.grep(shapes, function(e) { return e.id == shapeId; });

        if(result.length == 1) {

            return result[0];

        } else {

            return null;

        }

    }


    /**
     * draw
     *
     * @desc    draw shapes
     * @retuns  {void}
     */
    function draw() {

        // add shapes to the layer and register event listeners
        for(var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {

            var shapeObj = shapes[i];


            // add shape to layer
            circleLayer.add(shapeObj.shape);

            // register event listeners
            for(var n = 0; n < shapeObj.events.length; n++) {

                var eventObj = shapeObj.events[n];

                shapeObj.shape.on(eventObj.type, eventObj.callback);

            }

            // draw connections
            for(var m = 0; m < shapeObj.connections.length; m++) {

                var connectionObj = shapeObj.connections[m];

                // get ids
                var fromId  = shapeObj.id;
                var toId    = connectionObj.to;

                // check if connection is already drawn
                if(fromId > toId) {

                    // do not draw it again
                    continue;

                }

                // get coordinates
                var fromCoordinatesObj  = getCircleCenterCoordinates(fromId);
                var toCoordinatesObj    = getCircleCenterCoordinates(toId);

                // check coordinates
                if(typeof fromCoordinatesObj != 'object' || typeof toCoordinatesObj != 'object') {

                    // was not able to get valid coordinates
                    continue;

                }

                // update / set line points for this connection
                connectionObj.line.attrs.points = [fromCoordinatesObj.x, fromCoordinatesObj.y, toCoordinatesObj.x, toCoordinatesObj.y];

                // add line to layer
                connectorLayer.add(connectionObj.line);

            }

        }


        // add the layers to the stage
        stage.add(connectorLayer);
        stage.add(circleLayer);

    }


    /**
     * init shapes and layers
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    // create stage
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'canvas',
        width: 700,
        height: 500
    });


    // create layers
    var circleLayer     = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var connectorLayer  = new Kinetic.Layer();


    // define shapes
    var shapes = [

        {
            id:     1001,
            label:  'me',
            shape:  new Kinetic.Circle({
                x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 200,
                y: stage.getHeight() / 2 + 100,
                radius: 70,
                fill: '#DDD',
                stroke: '#EFEFEF',
                strokeWidth: 10,
                draggable: true
            }),
            events: [
                {type: 'mouseover', callback: function() { console.log('over 1');}}
            ],
            connections: [
                {to: 2001, line: new Kinetic.Line({stroke: '#333', strokeWidth: 2})},
                {to: 3001, line: new Kinetic.Line({stroke: '#333', strokeWidth: 2})},
                {to: 4001, line: new Kinetic.Line({stroke: '#333', strokeWidth: 2})}
            ]

        },
        {
            id:     2001,
            label:  'you',
            shape:  new Kinetic.Circle({
                x: stage.getWidth() / 2 + 200,
                y: stage.getHeight() / 2 + 100,
                radius: 70,
                fill: '#DDD',
                stroke: '#EFEFEF',
                strokeWidth: 10,
                draggable: true
            }),
            events: [
                {type: 'mouseover', callback: function() { console.log('over 2');}}
            ],
            connections: [
                {to: 1001, line: new Kinetic.Line({stroke: '#333', strokeWidth: 2})},
                {to: 3001, line: new Kinetic.Line({stroke: '#333', strokeWidth: 2})},
                {to: 4001, line: new Kinetic.Line({stroke: '#333', strokeWidth: 2})}
            ]
        },
        {
            id:     3001,
            label:  'her',
            shape:  new Kinetic.Circle({
                x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
                y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 100,
                radius: 70,
                fill: '#DDD',
                stroke: '#EFEFEF',
                strokeWidth: 10,
                draggable: true
            }),
            events: [
                {type: 'mouseover', callback: function() { console.log('over 3');}}
            ],
            connections: [
                {to: 1001, line: new Kinetic.Line({stroke: '#333', strokeWidth: 2})},
                {to: 2001, line: new Kinetic.Line({stroke: '#333', strokeWidth: 2})}
            ]
        },
        {
            id:     4001,
            label:  'his',
            shape:  new Kinetic.Circle({
                x: 100,
                y: 150,
                radius: 70,
                fill: '#DDD',
                stroke: '#EFEFEF',
                strokeWidth: 10,
                draggable: true
            }),
            events: [
                {type: 'mouseover', callback: function() { console.log('over 4');}},
                {type: 'dragend', callback: function() { console.log(this.getPosition()); console.log(shapes[3]);  }}
            ],
            connections: [
                {to: 1001, line: new Kinetic.Line({stroke: '#333', strokeWidth: 2})},
                {to: 2001, line: new Kinetic.Line({stroke: '#333', strokeWidth: 2})}
            ]
        }

    ];


    // draw shapes
    draw();

</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use Kinetic.Group for that?

Comment: Hy Elsa and thanks for your reply! I'm pretty new to KineticJs. After checking the manual it doesn't lool like a solution for my problem. If I put my connection-line from node A to node B in one group, the other node won't know about it, right? I just want a "sticky"-line to node A and B which also moves, when node A or node B moves. thank you.

Comment: Well if you create a group, and then add to it whatever nodes you want (the line and the circles for example) and set them to draggable properly, the whole group will move together when you drag one item. That's what I understood you want to do until now :-) you're welcome and good luck!

Comment: ah now I see, where you misunderstand my problem :) I just want to move the lines which are connected to the circle I moved. circle A is moved. Circle B and C are still in the same position. But the lines from circle B and C to circle A has to move to new center of circle A. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's how to keep 2 nodes connected with a Kinetic.Line.**

- Create a Kinetic.Line with points set to connect the 2 nodes you wish to connect.
- Listen for dragmove events on the 2 nodes you wish to connect.
- On dragmove of either node, reset the connecting line's points to again connect to the 2 nodes.

Something like this...

```
NodeA.on('dragmove',function(){
    connectorAB.points([NodeA.x(),nodeA.y(),nodeB.x(),nodeB.y()]);
    layer.draw();
});

// same thing for NodeB
```

Comment: Thank you markE! It works almost. When I move my nodes, the line will be drawn as expected, but the old lines still appears. Do I have to clean the layer or something else? I'm currently just updating the points in my KineticJs Line Object and then call the draw() function. Thank you

Comment: if you have the circle and the connectors in different layers, you have to update both layers. Eitherway `stage.draw()` might work.